# Angular2: Unsubscribe from http observable in Service

Tags: angular, rxjs5, unsubscribe

What is the best practice to unsubscribe within a Angular2 service from a http subscription?

Currently I do this but I'm not sure if this will be the best way.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { ISubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    private _searchSource = new Subject<any>();

    public search$ = this._searchSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    public search(value: string) {
        let sub: ISubscription = this._http.get("/api/search?value=" + value)
            .map(response => <any>response.json())
            .do(data => this._searchSource.next(data))
            .finally(() => sub.unsubscribe()).subscribe();
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems redundant and pointless to unsubscribe when the observable completes.

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer Well it was not my question if it makes sense my question was: Whats the best practice. So?

Comment: I don't think there are best practices for things that don't make sense :D Perhaps just - don't do it.

Comment: And what shouldn't I do? @günter-zöchbauer Maybe an explanation would be great instead of unhelpful comments

Answer (score 145, accepted):

A Service in Angular is a singleton. This means that the service will exist for the entire lifespan of your application.

The reason that you need to unsubscribe from an observable, is to avoid memory leaks. When do you get memory leaks? If something has been garbage collected while it was still subscribed to an observable, event listener, socket, ...

Since an Angular service never get's destroyed, unless your entire application get's destroyed, there is no real reason to unsubscribe from it. The observable will either complete or error or keep going as long as your application does.

Conclusion: Unsubscribing in a service is kind of pointless, since there is no chance of memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kwintenp. But as you see above, Every call of the search method will create a new observable which I have to subscribe to get the data. Didn't I have to unsubscribe the subscription to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: That is ok. Every subscription returned will clean themselves up. The HTTP service cleans up after itself. When the XHR result is received, the subscription’s complete method is called and therefore unsubscribes itself.
 
However, there could be a case for calling the unsubscribe method on the http service’s returned Observable. If we ever wanted to cancel our on going HTTP request we would call unsubscribe. This calls abort under the covers to complete the clean up.

Comment: "the service will exist for the entire lifespan of your application" is not true. I can provide a service just for the lifetime of a component, so that it gets destroyed when the component gets destroyed...

Comment: "Conclusion: Unsubscribing in a service is kind of pointless, since there is no chance of memory leaks."

I think it's more accurate to say that unsubscribing to observables created by angular's http service is not needed.  There could be a situation where a service shared by two components references some object inside the subscription.  If that shared service gets garbage collected (see @MarkusE. comment above) you can end up with a memory leak.

Comment: If some observables shared between components that are exposed through an Angular service, for example, they may be subscribed multiple times as long as the component is initialized. So we must always unsubscribe from them.

Comment: Are we worried about memory usage at all?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but felt like adding this cause I came here seeking information on how to unsubscribe from observables inside a service when they aren't singletons (specially). I stick to the format of returning the observable as part of the response interface, for the calling component to be able to unsubscribe to it whenever it wishes. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a terrible answer, which is wrong in almost any way it can be. In fairness, Angular's changed a lot since 2016, but that's not the only reason it's wrong. Look at the @kfir-erez answer for the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476730/127826

Answer (score 24):

I disagree with [KwintenP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885304/1986423) answer.
Yes in case of observable to HttpClient call there is no need to unsubscribe as [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925660/1986423) mentioned correctly however in other observables you may definitely need to unsubscribe in a service.

Let see simple example: Assume we have a store that send observables and in the store we have a `clicker` observable that fire `true` whenever there is a click on the right mouse (for some weird reason)
And assume we have `MyWeirdService` that do the following:

```
class MyWeirdService {
  doSomethingUnthinkableManyTimes() {
    this.store.select('clicker').subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Hey what do you know, I'm leaking");
    });
  }
}
```

`this.store.select('clicker')` returns an observable that we registering a new handler to it on every call to `doSomethingUnthinkableManyTimes` without cleaning it resulting in memory leak that will stay as long as the service is there (application lifetime in many cases)

Bottom line you don't need to unsubscribe in the case above of Http as [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925660/1986423) explained it well but in other cases you may need it.

-------------- Edition ------------

To solve that issue in my example, just add `take(1)` and it will unsubscribe automatically after each stream is fired:

```
class MyWeirdService {
  doSomethingUnthinkableManyTimes() {
    this.store.select('clicker')
     .pipe(take(1))
     .subscribe(() => {
      console.log("What a relief, I'm not leaking anymore");
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Awesome, Kfir Erez should have went through the rough road of observable unsubscription issue in services. I have found your answer to be very helpful. @KwintenP I would recommend this to be the answer for the question to not mislead others

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to unsubscribe from observable created by `Http` or `HttpClient` because it is finite observable (value will be emitted only once and `complete` will be called).

However, you CAN unsubscribe from the observable created by `HttpClient` to **cancel the request**. It mean you are no longer interested in data returned by the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
You need to understand that the service file should be used to just define the http methods and not subscribe there itself. 
Create the method in the service file, use Dependency injection to inject that service in the component and then use ngOnDesteoy to kill the subscription 

****** this is in your component.ts file *******
// introduce a new subject variable to destroy the subscription
destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

constructor(private serviceName: yoirService){} // Dependency injection 

// wherever you want to unsubsribe an observable or a subscription
this.serviceName.observableName.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(
    // required code 
);

//  use ngOnDestroy() to kill it
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.destroy$.next();
   this.destroy$.complete();
}

This way you'll destroy the service once the component is destroyed.
```