# Do I need to unsubscribe the Observable within a Promise?

Tags: angular, rxjs

[image]

Do I need to unsubscribe any of the above Observables? What does take(1) really do? Lastly, how do you use async-await in this context? (Is it better to use async-await?)

New to Angular. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861494/angular2-unsubscribe-from-http-observable-in-service

Comment: You don't have to unsubscribe. take(1) makes it clear that observable will complete after one emission

Comment: @xdeepakv I am not doing this in a service.ts

Comment: @cuddlemeister Thanks, in case of Question1, do I need to unsubscribe if I don't have take(1)? even if it is wrapped in a Promise?

Comment: @Richard well, http module provides observables, that fire only once. But it's a good practice to always make sure you won't have any memory leaks due to not-unsubscribed observables. Wrapping observable in a promise is not a good idea, since it's much better to have it like you did in `Question2`. Answering your question: when  you wrap observable in a promise, you will still have an observable, so ye, you need to unsubscribe or use `take(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need `take(1)` really depends on what `getPassengersByBid` does. If this method returns an Observable that emits just one item and then completes you don't need to use `take(1)` because it completes itself. For example `httpClient.get()` makes one `next` and one `complete` so you don't need to chain it with `take(1)`.

If  `getPassengersByBid` is an infinite Observable that never completes then it makes sense to use `take(1)` if you want just one value.

Second thing is that you don't need to wrap Observables with Promises and you can use just `toPromise()`. However, be aware that with `toPromise()` the source Observable has to complete and that the Promise will be resolved with the most recent value (but if you use `take(1)` you'll have the same behavior to what you have right now even with Observables that emit multiple items).

Comment: getPassengersByBid() is an infinite Observable. In your last paragraph, it seems like toPromise() won't work on infinite Observables because they never complete. So I think I do need to wrap the Observable in a Promise, plus I need to edit the return data from the Observable and return something different as a Promise. Anyway, your answer clears a lot of things up for me. Thank you.

Comment: Answer to my own comment. toPromise() does work on infinite Observable only if you use it with take(1) I believe. But I don't want to return the data from the Observable as the return data of the Promise. That is why I need to wrap it in a "new Promise()" so that I can edit the data and return whatever I want as the Promise. Someone please let me know if my logic is correct. Thanks

Comment: You're right. If your Observable is infinite then you have to use `take(1)` because otherwise `toPromise()` will never resolve. You can use other operators after `take(1)` to transform data to whatever you want and still use `toPromise()`.